# ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, scrapinghub

I am a beginner in scrapy, python. I tried to deploy the spider code in scrapinghub and I encountered the following error. Below is the code.

```
import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,SoupStrainer
import urllib2
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
import re
import pkgutil
from pkg_resources import resource_string
from tues1402.items import Tues1402Item

data = pkgutil.get_data("tues1402","resources/urllist.txt")
class SpiderTuesday (scrapy.Spider):     
    name = 'tuesday'
    self.start_urls = [url.strip() for url in data]
    def parse(self, response):
       story = Tues1402Item()
       story['url'] = response.url
       story['title'] = response.xpath("//title/text()").extract()
       return story
```

is my spider.py code

```
import scrapy
class Tues1402Item(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()
```

is the items.py code and

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name         = 'tues1402',
    version      = '1.0',
    packages     = find_packages(),
    entry_points = {'scrapy': ['settings = tues1402.settings']},
    package_data = {'tues1402':['resources/urllist.txt']},
    zip_safe = False,
)
```

is the setup.py code.

The following is the error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 126, in _next_request
>       request = next(slot.start_requests)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/**init**.py", line 70, in start_requests
>       yield self.make_requests_from_url(url)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/**init**.py", line 73, in make_requests_from_url
>       return Request(url, dont_filter=True)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/**init**.py", line 25, in **init**
>       self._set_url(url)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/**init**.py", line 57, in _set_url
>       raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
>   ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error means that url `h` is not a valid url. You should print out your `self.start_urls` and see what urls you have there, you most likely have a string `h` as your first url.

Seems like your spider iterates through text instead of a list of urls here:

```
data = pkgutil.get_data("tues1402","resources/urllist.txt")
class SpiderTuesday (scrapy.Spider):     
    name = 'tuesday'
    self.start_urls = [url.strip() for url in data]
```

Assuming that you store your urls with some separator in `urllist.txt` file you should split that:

```
# assuming file has url in every line
self.start_urls = [url.strip() for url in data.splitlines()]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Granitosaurus.

Comment: @Niveram no problem, if it solved your issue feel free to click accept answer button to the left of the answer! :)